# Matching portions of a regex

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to match a rewrite rule when there is a valid starting part of a domain, such as:

```
/asd-
/asd-f
/asd-f4.
/asd-f4.n
/asd-f4.n
/asd-f4.net
```

I don't want it to match in these invalid starting domains:

```
/-
/-as
/as--
/asdf.4
```

I know its not fully inclusive, but I'm defining a valid domain as:

- Starts and ends with a letter or number (excluding the dot and the tld part)
- Be 1 character or longer and less than 63 characters in length (excluding the dot and the tld part)
- Contains only letters, numbers, or hyphens (excluding the dot and the tld part)
- Does not contain two or more hyphens in a row
- Ends in .com, .net, or .org

Right now my regex matches valid domains, but I'm not really getting if it just starts with a valid domain name.

```
RewriteRule ^/(((?!-)(?!.*--)[A-Za-z0-9-](?<!-)){1,63}(\.(com|net|org)))$ /?domain=$1 [NC]
```

Comment: Check https://regex101.com/r/vq4vmF/2

Comment: `RewriteRule` only matches `REQUEST_URI` not the domain name.

Comment: This would be a lot simpler if broken into a sequence of conditions.

Comment: You should clarify what are you trying to do in this `RewriteRule`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you need, but will try anyway.
*Note that the last part `\.(com|net|org)` is required as I think you state.*

If the *last* part is *not* required, then you have to use
some other *anchoring* like `(\.(com|net|org)|(?!\S))` or similar.

`/([a-zA-Z0-9]|(?<!/)-(?!-)){1,63}\.(com|net|org)`

Expanded

```
 /  
 (
      [a-zA-Z0-9] 
   |  (?<! / )
      -
      (?! - )
 ){1,63}
 \.
 ( com | net | org )
```

---

Alternatively, you *can* match a progression, but it still needs some
anchoring at the end (can be anything).

`/([a-zA-Z0-9]|(?<!/)-(?!-)){1,63}(\.(c(om?)?|n(et?)?|o(rg?)?)?)?(?!\S)`

https://regex101.com/r/4bmeCT/1

Expanded

```
 /
 (
      [a-zA-Z0-9] 
   |  (?<! / )
      -
      (?! - )
 ){1,63}
 (
      \.
      (
           c
           ( om? )?
        |  n
           ( et? )?
        |  o
           ( rg? )?
      )?
 )?
 (?! \S )  # some anchoring required here
```